# ASP.NET MVC When should we use RenderAction Instead of DisplayFor or RenderPartial?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For displaying partial view models, I see three options, either `@{ Html.RenderAction(); }`, `@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.OtherModel);` or using `@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.OtherModel)` with display templates.

I have cut code down for brevity.

The first option, using `@Html.RenderAction()` means that we don't need to do our binding initially in the first `ActionResult`, but later on in the `PartialViewResult` and we don't need to have a child object in our view model. The other two options allows us to map the child object, in this case the `IEnumerable<SideBarSongDto> SideBarSongDtos` initially in the `ActionResult`, so I presume this reduces the number of HttpRequests as we don't need to call another action again to get the data.

ViewModels:

```
public class SongDto
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     //Needed if we use RenderPartial or display templates
     public IEnumerable<SideBarSongDto> SideBarSongDtos { get; set; }       
}

public class SideBarSongDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AudioName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var SongDto = new SongDto();

    SongDto.SideBarSongDtos = Context.Songs
            .Select(x => new SideBarSongDto { AudioName = x.AudioName, ArtistName = x.ArtistName });   
}

//Optional depending on if we use `RenderAction`
public PartialViewResult SidebarPartial(int id)
{
    var songs = Context.Songs.ToList();
    var sideBarSongsDto = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Song>, IEnumerable<SideBarSongDto>>(songs);

    return PartialView("_SideBar", sideBarSongsDto);
}
```

_SideBar Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SideBarSongDto>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-side-bar">
        <div class="side-bar">
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <span class="song-name side-bar-text">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.AudioName)</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="artist-name side-bar-text">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ArtistName)</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Song View:

```
@model SongDto

<section id="music-grid">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("SidebarPartial", new { id = Model.Id }); }
</section>
```

or

```
@model SongDto

<section id="music-grid">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SideBar", Model.SideBarSongDtos); }
</section>
```

or we could use a `DisplayFor` and have a display template instead.

```
@model SongDto

<section id="music-grid">
    @DisplayFor(x => Model.SideBarSongDtos)
</section>
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is it better in this instance to use `RenderPartial` instead where we can as we don't have to call the `ActionResult` again and cut down on HttpRequests?
2. When would we ever need `RenderAction`?
3. I see no difference in the `DisplayFor` using a model and display templates and that of `RenderPartial`, when do we choose one or the other?

Comment: No. 3: For display only views, there is no real difference, but for editing, `RenderPartial` will not generate the correct name attributes (unless you pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as `AddditionalViewData` where as `EditorFor()` will.

Comment: you know you can also just use `@Html.Partial("partialVIewName", modelobject)` http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/Q8V2130113-RenderPartial-vs-RenderAction-vs-Partial-vs-Action-in-MVC-Razor.html

Comment: @JamieD77 renderpartial is faster.